VBA macro to scan entire document for instances of a string followed by a numeral, eg, "cat 104", etc., and return the strings with numerals in a list
PROBLEM
I'm trying (to no avail) to come up with a VBA macro which scans an entire document for instances of a string followed by a reference numeral, e.g., "dog 102", "cat 104", "owner 106", etc., and then returns an ascending order list of all unique instances of the strings with their corresponding numerals listed in parentheses, e.g.:
Ref Numeral List:
dog (102)
cat (104)
owner (106)
...
This code gets me some of the way there, but it's not right:
Sub PrintRefNumList()
Dim doc As Document
Dim rng As Range
Dim strPattern As String
Dim regEx As Object
Dim matches As Object
Dim uniqueStrings As Collection
Dim i As Long
Dim result As String

' Set your document (modify as needed)
Set doc = ActiveDocument

' Define the pattern for finding strings followed by numerals (excluding percentages within 3 characters)
strPattern = "([a-zA-Z]+ ){1,7}(\d+)(?![\d%]{0,3}%)"

' Create a regular expression object
Set regEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
regEx.Global = True
regEx.IgnoreCase = True
regEx.Pattern = strPattern

' Initialize the collection for unique strings
Set uniqueStrings = New Collection

' Search the entire document
Set rng = doc.Content
Set matches = regEx.Execute(rng.text)

' Loop through the matches
For Each match In matches
    Dim str As String
    Dim numeral As String
    str = match.SubMatches(0)
    numeral = match.SubMatches(1)
    
    ' Exclude specific strings
    If Not (InStr(1, str, "claim", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, str, "figure", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, str, " and ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, str, " between ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, str, " as ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, str, " to ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, str, " from ", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
        On Error Resume Next
        uniqueStrings.Add str, str
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Next match

' Build the result string with bullet points
For i = 1 To uniqueStrings.count
    result = result & "- " & uniqueStrings(i) & "(" & GetNumeral(uniqueStrings(i), matches) & ")" & vbNewLine
Next i

' Insert the bulleted list into the document
If uniqueStrings.count > 0 Then
    doc.Content.InsertAfter vbNewLine & "REF NUMERAL LIST:" & vbNewLine & result
Else
    MsgBox "No matches found."
End If
End Sub

Function GetNumeral(str As String, matches As Object) As String
Dim match As Variant
For Each match In matches
    If match.SubMatches(0) = str Then
        GetNumeral = match.SubMatches(1)
        Exit Function
    End If
Next match
End Function

The issue is, as well as failing to provide the list in ascending order, certain words are being returned in the list that I would want to be filtered out by default.  For example, "Figure (#)", "claim (#)", or "as (#)", or "between (#)", or "and (#)", etc.  None of these are strings (nouns) as intended and they shouldn't be listed with numerals.  I want those strings to be ignored - they appeared next to numbers in the document somewhere and have been accidentally caught by the macro.  I want a section of the code that hard-removes all strings from the Ref Numeral List which contain those specific standalone words.  This code
' Exclude specific strings
    If Not (InStr(1, str, "claim", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, str, "figure", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, str, " and ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, str, " between ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, str, " as ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, str, " to ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Or InStr(1, str, " from ", vbTextCompare) > 0) Then
        On Error Resume Next
        uniqueStrings.Add str, str
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Next match

works for the words "claim" and "figure" but not for words like "as", "between", "and", etc., for some reason.  I tried modifying
strPattern = "([a-zA-Z]+ ){1,7}(\d+)(?![\d%]{0,3}%)"

to do some kind of lookbehind to exclude specific terms (claim│figure│between│and) and so on, but it never worked and just caused errors.  Any ideas as to how I can add these hard filters to remove stray strings from my Ref Numeral List?

Since your search pattern must begin with a letter, the first letter letter of your InStr search pattern must also be a letter, or it will never be found. However, if you search for "as " being greater than zero, you will ignore potential positives like, perhaps, "fajitas ". To avoid that, always make sure that your InStr looks only at the match in the first position.
' Exclude specific strings
    If Not ( InStr(1, str, "claim ", vbTextCompare) = 1 _
          Or InStr(1, str, "figure ", vbTextCompare) = 1 _
          Or InStr(1, str, "and ", vbTextCompare) = 1 _
          Or InStr(1, str, "between ", vbTextCompare) = 1 _
          Or InStr(1, str, "as ", vbTextCompare) = 1 _
          Or InStr(1, str, "to ", vbTextCompare) = 1 _
          Or InStr(1, str, "from ", vbTextCompare) = 1) Then
        On Error Resume Next
        uniqueStrings.Add str, str
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If

